# Onenote crashes Lenovo Power manager which crashes explorer

Tags: windows-7, printer, crash, thinkpad, microsoft-onenote

Everytime that I restart windows on my Thinkpad it resets my default printer to OneNote (part of microsoft's bloatware). The problem is, if I forget to change it back to the actuall printer then when I go to print something OneNote crashes without a log entry and Lenovo Power Manager pops up and says it's stopped working. This is followed by a warning that explorer has crashed and needs to be restarted. Clicking "ok" just closes it and I have to ctrl+alt+del to task manager to manually restart it.

Anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

According to Microsoft support it's Lenovo's fault and Lenovo says it's Microsoft's fault. Since neither could offer any real help I figured I'd give SU a try.

Comment: If you're simply trying to print something, and Lenovo's "Power Manager" crashes, then (based on what's here) I'd say that's Lenovo's problem.   Ensure you're using the latest drivers/Power Manager software from Lenovo.   Or, why not just uninstall the Lenovo Power Manager? Windows has it's own power management, and 90% of Lenovo notebook utilities are just bloat.

Comment: If you don't use OneNote and won't need to print to the OneNote printer, just remove the OneNote printer.